# get subtrings before and after space and all the combinations

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I got a table with a unique column named 'sentence'

```
Create Table Test(
sentence VARCHAR2(100);
);
```

and

```
Insert into Test('this is a message');
```

Basically what I want to achieve is to get all the substring after and before the space. However the query that i execute only takes the substring before the space

```
SELECT (Regexp_substr (sentence, '^[^ ]+ ')) sentence_new 
FROM Test
GROUP BY sentence;
```

And the result i want is

```
RESULT
---------------------
This
is
a
test
This is
This a
This test
is test
is this
is a
a This
a is
a test
Test this
test a
test is
This is a 
This is test
This a test
a is this
a test this
a this is
is this a
is test a
is this test
test a this
test is this
test this is
```

Comment: Why don't your desired results include any two-word combinations that start with "a" or with "test"? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Sorry for that, but you are 100% correct, i want to get all the posible combinations from the substrings obtained after and before any space.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917027/oracle-string-combinatorial-permutation

Comment: "All the combinations" should also include the four-word permutations, right? And then, perhaps, for consistency, the null string as well (a "combination" of zero words). You will get a very large number of such "combinations".

Answer (score 0):

The problem has two parts.

The first part is to create a view (result of a query) that will have the four words, separated at each space. You were already able to do that. **EDIT**: Actually, on re-reading, you weren't. See below (bottom of this Answer).

The second part is to get all the "combinations" of 1, 2, 3 or 4 **distinct** words, separated by space. For mathematical correctness, you should probably also include the empty string as a combination of 0 words, but that can be solved separately.

One way to do that is with a hierarchical query. Here is an example, which will produce all the combinations of 1, 2, 3 or 4 distinct values from the set {1, 2, 3, 4}. Note that the result will also have a leading space; you may remove it with `ltrim()`. I don't show the output, since it's 64 rows, but you can run it on your database.

```
with
     inputs ( n ) as (
       select 1 from dual union all
       select 2 from dual union all
       select 3 from dual union all
       select 4 from dual
     )
--  end of test data; SQL query begins below this line
select sys_connect_by_path(n, ' ') as result
from   inputs
connect by nocycle prior n > 0
;
```

Adapt this to your exercise - instead of `inputs` you should select from the result of your first query (where you split the sentence into individual words), and instead of `n` you should use the column alias you created there (`sentence_new`).

**Edit** - I re-read your post and see you weren't able to split the sentence into all its component words. That is done with another hierarchical query. How complicated that is depends on whether you have just one row in the input, or many. The easy one is if you have just one row:

```
SELECT (Regexp_substr (sentence, '[^ ]+ ', 1, level)) sentence_new 
FROM Test
connect by level <= 1 + regexp_count(sentence, ' +')
```