# How to change words position in all variants in sentence

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

for example 'A B C' is my sentence, i want to change words position in all variants. Like..

```
'A B C'
'A C B'
'B C A'
'B A C'
'C A B'
'C B A'
```

thank u

Comment: So `'B A C'` should be replace by `'A B C'`?

Comment: Have you tried anything? SO is not for questions like "How to do this". Please try something and then, if you have an issue with your code, post a question here.

Comment: This can be done, but do you realize that if your input sentence has many words, you will get a very, very large number of rows very quickly? If the input has 100 words, do you realize how large 100! is? (100 factorial)

Comment: this function will use only for sentences with max 4 words

Comment: something like [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917027/oracle-string-combinatorial-permutation)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza thank u, did it like : SELECT  a.www from 
(WITH words AS
(   SELECT  REGEXP_SUBSTR( '&txt', '\S+', 1, LEVEL )    AS word
        ,   LEVEL                                       AS num
    FROM    DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH( REGEXP_REPLACE( '&txt', '\S+\s*', 'X' ) )
)
SELECT  SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( W.word, ' ' ) www
FROM    words   W
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR W.num != W.num) a WHERE LENGTH(TRIM(a.www))=LENGTH(TRIM('&txt'))

Comment: If you solve your problem you can post it as an answer, or mark as duplicated of the one I suggest so other now this is already solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts to the problem.

The first part is to split the input sentence into words. This is a separate question, there are many threads on Stack Overflow (more than 100) that show how that is done, and I assume your question is more about the permutations.

The second part is, once you have the individual words, how do you get all the permutations. One way is using hierarchical queries, as discussed in the Comments under the original post; however, the older solutions seem overly complicated. Here is the simplest way you can do it with a hierarchical query:

```
with
     test_data ( str ) as (
       select 'alpha' from dual union all
       select 'beta'  from dual union all
       select 'gamma' from dual
     )
-- end of test data
select     trim(sys_connect_by_path(str, ' ')) as perm
from       test_data
where      connect_by_isleaf = 1
connect by nocycle prior str is not null
;

PERM
----------------
alpha beta gamma
alpha gamma beta
beta alpha gamma
beta gamma alpha
gamma alpha beta
gamma beta alpha
```

The only reason we have the condition `PRIOR STR IS NOT NULL` is just so we have a condition in which `STR` appears with the `PRIOR` operator. The columns that are subject to the `PRIOR` operator in `CONNECT BY` are the ones that define "cycles" in hierarchical queries. The `NOCYCLE` directive means we shouldn't have repeated values of `STR` in the output - that's exactly what we want. Since I didn't really need any condition on `STR`, I just wanted to have it with the `PRIOR` operator, I wrote a trivial condition, `PRIOR STR IS NOT NULL`. All the work is really done by the hierarchical query, with `NOCYCLE`, and of course by `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH`. The `TRIM` is needed because without it the output begins with a space (the result of `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH`). The `WHERE` clause, using `CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF`, is needed because we only want the full permutations, we don't also want the individual words, and the permutations of two-word subsets. (Just leave the `WHERE` clause out to see what that does.)

Answer (score 0):

thank u @mathguy..

```
WITH WORDS AS
 (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(P_TEXT1, '\S+', 1, LEVEL) AS WORD, LEVEL AS NUM
    FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(P_TEXT1, '\S+\s*', 'X')))
SELECT TRIM(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(W.WORD, ' ')) AS PERM
  FROM WORDS W
 WHERE CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR W.WORD IS NOT NULL
```